# How teardown_request() works with Python- Flask?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I received internal error with message:

```
"TimeoutError: QueuePool limit of size 5 overflow 10 reached, connection timed out, timeout 30"
```

and searching online gave teardown_request() solution :

```
@app.teardown_request
def checkin_db(exc):
    try:
        print "Removing db session."
        db.session.remove()
    except AttributeError:
        pass
```

Now timeout error is gone. But I didn't understand teardown_request completely,  look like db.session.remove() will be invoked after every request ? or every error? Is it safe to use this code?

Comment: How are you opening connections? Are you closing them after your tx is completed? Are you using Flask-SQLAlchemy module? Are you creating your own session?

Comment: thanks for the response.

After setting password details, connection is established via "db = SQLAlchemy(app)" If each request is Tx , then yes. Like closing them after '/login' , but user can access '/profile' page without any issues.
Yes, Flask SqlAchemy module is used. The code relies on Flask session. We don't create own sessions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`teardown_request` registers a function to be called at the end of each request whether it was successful or an exception was raised. It is a good place to cleanup request scope objects like a database session/transaction. That is all your code sample is doing.

It is safe to use that code and `db.session.remove()` will be called after **every** request (even if an exception occurs during the request)

See [Flask Callbacks and Errors](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/reqcontext/#callbacks-and-errors) and [Flask.teardown_request](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.teardown_request) for more information

Comment: Just one quick question, Say user logged into the site, now db.session.remove() will be invoked? Then how he/she is able to access his 'profile settings' page without need to re-login?

Comment: db.session.remove() just cleans up database session not Flask session. Flask session is by default stored in a cookie which is passed from the client with each request. db.session.remove() makes sure any database transactions you were doing either committed successfully or rolled back

Comment: What is the difference between `@app.teardown_request` and `@app.teardown_appcontext`?

Comment: @junnytony when do we really implement teardown request i.e if done during app development stage, if there is a bug it will never get resolved is my concern until unless we log the exception and check it regularly