# Returning an immediate response in flask, but finishing the processing in a new thread

Tags: python, multithreading, flask

I have a process from 10 seconds, but after the 10 seconds, I don't need to return the information to the user but write it down on a dynamoDB, that's why I would like the user doesn't have to wait 10 seconds. Instead, I would like an immediate "Success" response after the post request.

I read a couple of posts and in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17293311/flask-end-response-and-continue-processing) one, the answer was with a Teardown Callback, but there wasn't an example.

I read then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30521112/how-teardown-request-works-with-python-flask), but it doesn't help me with my problem.

I read of course [teardown-callbacks](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/reqcontext/#teardown-callbacks) and [this pattern](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/53/) but I don't know how I could use it another way.

My code looks like this:

```
@app.route('/ocr/read_image', methods=['POST'])
def get_text():    
    return jsonify('Success')

@app.teardown_request
def teardown_request(response):        
    time.sleep(10)
```

It actually returns the "Success" Message but just after the 10 seconds.

Is there a way to return the "Succes" Message before the 10 seconds?

I've been reading that it's maybe possible with celery but I would love avoid it if I can.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: If you don't actually need a new thread per-se but just want to do work after the response, I posted this answer that is pretty slick: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66675113/848419 Benefit is that you get to keep local function context, so no awkward passing of variables.  Note that request/response context is gone, so you need to copy to local vars first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Ardaglio said, the best way was using multithreading.

I didn't use Celery, because I think it's pretty complicated and my problem is quite easy for it.

So, I'm using Thread:

```
from threading import Thread

@app.route('/ocr/read_image', methods=['POST'])
def get_text():    
    Thread(target=continue_processing).start()
    return jsonify('Success')

def continue_processing():
    time.sleep(10)
    print('Hi')
```

But, you gotta be careful. I'm using Keras with Tensorflow as Backend, and if you use it so, you will have a nice value error `ValueError: Tensor Tensor()is not an element of this graph.`

So, to avoid it inside a Thread, you've to save the Graph after the model is made:

`GRAPH = tf.get_default_graph()`

and then you've to use it inside the asynchron process this way:

```
with GRAPH.as_default():
    do something with your model
```

Hope it could be help someone.

Comment: in what way is mentioning keras/tensorflow "on-topic" with this question?

Comment: In no way because it doesn't have anything to do with keras/tensorflow? The question was about how to show "Success," but continue with the process behind. The Keras/Tensorflow "topic" was just an extra because I was having a problem with it.

Answer (score 6):

Threading complicates things unnecessarily here as well imho. To do what you're looking to do without introducing threads you can hook into the [WSGI response close method](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/#specification-details). The simplest way to do this is by using the werkzeug [ClosingIterator](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.14/wsgi/#werkzeug.wsgi.ClosingIterator) helper.

```
import traceback
from werkzeug.wsgi import ClosingIterator

class AfterThisResponse:
    def __init__(self, app=None):
        self.callbacks = []
        if app:
            self.init_app(app)

    def __call__(self, callback):
        self.callbacks.append(callback)
        return callback

    def init_app(self, app):
        # install extensioe
        app.after_this_response = self

        # install middleware
        app.wsgi_app = AfterThisResponseMiddleware(app.wsgi_app, self)

    def flush(self):
        try:
            for fn in self.callbacks:
                try:
                    fn()
                except Exception:
                    traceback.print_exc()
        finally:
            self.callbacks = []

class AfterThisResponseMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, application, after_this_response_ext):
        self.application = application
        self.after_this_response_ext = after_this_response_ext

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        iterator = self.application(environ, start_response)
        try:
            return ClosingIterator(iterator, [self.after_this_response_ext.flush])
        except Exception:
            traceback.print_exc()
            return iterator
```

You then use this extension like this:

```
import flask
import time
app = flask.Flask("after_response")
AfterThisResponse(app)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    @app.after_this_response
    def post_process():
        time.sleep(2)
        print("after_response")

    return "Success!\n"
```

When you curl you will see an immediate success and then 2s later in your logs you will see your "after_response" message:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Jun/2018 16:15:01] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
after_response
```

This solution is a summary adapted from my answers:

- [Need to execute a function after returning the response in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082683/need-to-execute-a-function-after-returning-the-response-in-flask/51027637#51027637)
- [Flask end response and continue processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17293311/flask-end-response-and-continue-processing/51027454#51027454)
- [Execute a function after Flask returns response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48994440/execute-a-function-after-flask-returns-response/51013358#51013358)

Comment: Hi, Do you have any ideas that how can i use this within a blueprint?

Answer (score 1):

Celery can get your work done.

You need to perform some async process. It means exactly what you want: call 'someone' to process your information, then send a message to your user/application without waiting the return of the processed information.

Then, you can add a callback to notify something else when you finished processing it.

All that can be done with Celery or RabbitMQ.