# How to determine endpoint in "after response" handler?

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

I am developing a REST API in Flask. Some endpoints need to perform additional duties after the response is handled, but I would like to avoid using external processing queue or threads. One very convenient solution seems to be with WSGI Middleware and ClosingIterator, as outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51027874/593487). However the handler of each point needs to know which endpoint handled the request, in order to perform their post-mortem duties.

One idea is to decorate my endpoints like this:

```
@app.route('/api/status/info', methods=['GET'])
def get_status_info():
    @app.after_this_response('get_status_info')
    def say_hi():
        print('hi, unknown endpoint!')

    return 'ok', 200
```

Instead of `unknown endpoint` I would like to print `get_status_info`. Is this possible?

Even better, if I write a generic `@app.after_response` handler (as in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51013358/593487) by the same author), can I determine in it which endpoint was used for handling the request?

**EDIT:** Trying to use `flask.request.url_rule.endpoint` throws an exception:

```
RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.
```

Comment: The first thing that came to my mind are some daeomn-like threads. Have you considered this?

Comment: does `flask.request.url_rule.endpoint` get you what you need?

Comment: @SirNeuman I have edited the answer - unfortunately it doesn't work outside of request context.

Comment: @gonczor I would prefer it I could avoid threads (I have edited the answer to reflect that, thanks!). The solution with WSGI Middleware is actually perfect for what I need, I just need to be able to pass parameters to my handler (which I am almost sure can be done somehow, but my WSGI-foo is lacking :) ).

Comment: @johndodo If it's outside of the request context could you add `@copy_current_request_context` decorator to your `say_hi` function? http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.copy_current_request_context

Comment: @SirNeuman Yes, thank you, that works! But only if I use `@after_this_response`. Do you maybe know how I could get the current request context in case of [`@after_response`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51013358/593487) too?

Comment: @SirNeuman If you care to post an answer, I would be happy to accept it. And thank you again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the endpoint of the original request inside `@app.after_this_response` you can do the following:

```
@app.route('/api/status/info', methods=['GET'])
def get_status_info():

    @app.after_this_response('get_status_info')
    @flask.copy_current_request_context
    def say_hi():
        print('hi, %s', % (flask.request.url_rule.endpoint))

    return 'ok', 200
```

`flask.request.url_rule.endpoint` gives you the endpoint's name, however you lose the request context by default when it passes onto the `say_hi` function, which is why you need the `@copy_current_request_context` decorator to pass on the context. Reference to that decorator is here: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.copy_current_request_context

Comment: `after_this_response` does not seem to exist -- only `after_this_request`, which adds a temporary `after_request` handler and still runs before returning to the browser. However, there is a `response.call_on_close` decorator that does the job and can be paired with `copy_current_request_context`.

Comment: I should have read more carefully for where that method is coming from. In any case, I found a simpler way to do this without creating new middleware: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63080968/78903